# Rotate geometry shader-created quad by model view

Tags: opengl

I'm feeding GL_POINTS into the geometry shader. From each point, I'm creating a simple quad. This works, but when I rotate my View matrix, I want the quads to rotate as well.

If I use a pass-through vertex shader, and set my geometry shader like this:

```
void outputQuadFromPoint( vec4 pt ) {

    float distanceX = 0.01; // OpenGL space
    float distanceY = 0.01;

    vec4 v1 = vec4( pt.x - distanceX, pt.y + distanceY, pt.z, 1.0 );
    vec4 v2 = vec4( pt.x - distanceX, pt.y - distanceY, pt.z, 1.0 );
    vec4 v3 = vec4( pt.x + distanceX, pt.y + distanceY, pt.z, 1.0 );
    vec4 v4 = vec4( pt.x + distanceX, pt.y - distanceY, pt.z, 1.0 );

    vec4 rv1 = Projection * View * v1;
    vec4 rv2 = Projection * View * v2;
    vec4 rv3 = Projection * View * v3;
    vec4 rv4 = Projection * View * v4;

   gl_Position = rv1;
   EmitVertex();
   ...
   EndPrimitive();
}
```

I get nothing. However this works (except no rotation of quad).

```
void outputQuadFromPoint( vec4 pt ) {

    float distanceX = 10.0; // screen space pixels
    float distanceY = 10.0;

    pt = Projection * View * pt;

    vec4 v1 = vec4( pt.x - distanceX, pt.y + distanceY, pt.z, 1.0 );
    vec4 v2 = vec4( pt.x - distanceX, pt.y - distanceY, pt.z, 1.0 );
    vec4 v3 = vec4( pt.x + distanceX, pt.y + distanceY, pt.z, 1.0 );
    vec4 v4 = vec4( pt.x + distanceX, pt.y - distanceY, pt.z, 1.0 );

   gl_Position = v1;
   EmitVertex();
   ...
   EndPrimitive();
}
```

I know I'm misunderstanding something, but why can apply the Projection & View transformations to the input point, and then calculate the quad, but not calculate the quad in GL space and then apply the screen transforms?

Comment: Don't forget to copy the pt.w component after projection, too!